# Не работает код с гитхаба для вывода никнейма и аватарки игрока по его id с помощью официального сайта для доната

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, github, playwright

Проблема заключается в том, что playwright не может найти изображение на сайте и никнейм по его селектору. Много времени убил, и так и не смог понять, почему он выдает ошибку. Код и сайт, с которым я работаю, приложены

Сайт: https://store.standoff2.com

```
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright
import requests


def run(playwright: Playwright, id: str) -> None:
    browser = playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://store.standoff2.com/")
    page.get_by_placeholder("ID").click()
    page.get_by_placeholder("ID").fill(id)
    page.query_selector('//*[@id="boom"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/button').click()
    url = page.locator("img").nth(1).get_attribute("src") # Здесь ошибка поиска картинки, превышается лимит в 30000 мс. Если его убрать, то он никогда не найдет картинку. Причем если он будет искать первую картинку на сайте, а не вторую, то все он найдет, а вот остальные не хочет
    name = page.query_selector('//*[@id="boom"]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[2]').text_content() # Здесь программа не может найти никнейм, хотя селектор указан верно (вроде). Выдает None. то есть неправильно указан селектор. А он правильно указан. Либо я тупой, либо что-то намудрил разраб кода.
    context.close()
    browser.close()
    return [name, url]
```

Вернуть код должен данные, которые выделены на скриншоте
[image]